# Reac-ChartJs-2: Is there a way to show another chart on the tooltip by hovering over a line chart graph?

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

What would be the way to achieve something like the following feature using react-chartjs-2?

Would you recommend other libraries that could achieve the same?

[image]